# Mouseover and mouseout not working on firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, mouseover, mouseout

I want to try image slide show on mouseover and stop on mouse out
Following is my code: but with mouse over mouse out is also calling..its working fine on chrome...

```
default_image = '';
timer = 0;

jQuery('.sales-product-images').on('mouseover',function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var selector = jQuery(this);
    var pd_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var imageArray = jQuery.parseJSON(images);
    var product_images= imageArray[pd_id];
    default_image = jQuery(this).attr('data-image');
    console.log('default-image= ' + default_image);
    timer = setInterval(function(){selector.fadeOut("fast", function () {
        console.log(counter);
        if (counter === product_images.length) {
            console.log('==');
            counter = 0;
        }
        console.log('localhost/product/' + product_images[counter]);
        selector.attr('src', 'localhost/product/' + product_images[counter]);
        selector.fadeIn(2500);
        counter = counter+ 1;
    });
}, 2000)});


jQuery('.sales-product-images').on('mouseleave', function() {
    console.log('now end');
    // var counter = 0;
    clearInterval(timer);
)};
```

problem is: "now end" is also printed on mouseover in firefox.Which should not be.

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle or something like that...

Comment: User `mouseenter()` insteadOf `mouseover()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
jQuery('.sales-product-images').on('mouseout', function() {
   console.log('now end');
   // var counter = 0;
  clearInterval(timer);
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely caused by using `mouseover` with `mouseleave`, when it's paired event should be `mouseout`. The pairings can be seen below.

**mouseover / mouseout**

```
$( ".sales-product-images" )
   .mouseover(function() {
      console.log("mouse over");
   })
   .mouseout(function() {
      console.log("mouse out");
});
```

**mouseenter / mouseleave**

```
$( ".sales-product-images" )
   .mouseenter(function() {
      console.log("mouse enter");
   })
   .mouseleave(function() {
      console.log("mouse leave");
});
```

The above methods are shortcuts for the `.on("", function(){})` method.

You could rewrite your javascript as follows:

```
default_image = '';
timer = 0;

jQuery('.sales-product-images').mouseover(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var selector = jQuery(this);
    var pd_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var imageArray = jQuery.parseJSON(images);
    var product_images= imageArray[pd_id];
    default_image = jQuery(this).attr('data-image');
    console.log('default-image= ' + default_image);
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        selector.fadeOut("fast", function () {
            console.log(counter);
            if (counter === product_images.length) {
                console.log('==');
                counter = 0;
            }
            console.log('localhost/product/' + product_images[counter]);
            selector.attr('src', 'localhost/product/' + product_images[counter]);
            selector.fadeIn(2500);
            counter = counter+ 1;
        });
    }, 2000);
}).mouseout(function() {
    console.log('now end');
    // var counter = 0;
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Comment: thanks @Jeemusu, I have also used mouseout but on firefox "Now end" is printing while on mouseover

Comment: The very last set of brackets are in the wrong order in your code. Should be `});` not `)};`. Works fine for me in firefox when I fix these.